# style change after axios get url

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui

Hi I have strange behavior when I fetch the data from axios and try to set pagination. When I hover on select input the style is changing. Best describe  is by showing  you by example:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-vzqie

When pagination is loaded hover on select input

When you turn of axios await everithing is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't know why is this happening. 
However, I found a workaround: remove '*container*' prop from the parent Grid (you should also remove '*item*' prop from the direct son).

You can refer to this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-brgw9?fontsize=14) example.

If you do need the parent Grid as a container, let me know, and i'll try to dig deeper into that.

Comment: Woow Ido thanks for workaround. me either dont know why this happen. Very strange behavior. Im wondering whats is wrong axsios, flat pagination or something else. It's hard to check why.